# Karma Unit Test Cordova native Keyboard plugin HTML Doc not defined

Tags: angular, cordova, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-runner

When running Unit Tests with Karma I get following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__zone_symbol__addEventListener' of undefined
        at Platform.registerListener Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/platform/platform.js:573:1)
        at Keyboard.focusOutline Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/platform/keyboard.js:223:1)
        at new Keyboard Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/platform/keyboard.js:32:1)
        at _createClass Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:8800:1)
        at _createProviderInstance$1 Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:8764:1)
        at resolveNgModuleDep Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:8749:1)
        at NgModuleRef_.get Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:9737:1)
        at resolveDep Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:10212:1)
        at createClass Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:10083:1)
        at createDirectiveInstance Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js:9922:24)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
        at UserContext.<anonymous> Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/src/pages/storelocator/list/storelocator-list.spec.ts:83:17)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
        at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:1)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:1)
        at ZoneQueueRunner.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute Users/berfuc/workspace/paysafecash-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:1)
```

my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],

angularCli: {
  environment: 'prod'
},

// plugins to use
plugins: [
  require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-junit-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage')
],

client:{
  clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
},

reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],

junitReporter: {
  outputDir: '',
  outputFile: 'test-results.xml',
  useBrowserName: false
},

// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: false,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: true

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
// concurrency: Infinity
})
};
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "es2017"
],
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
],
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@app/env": [
    "environments/environment"
  ]
}
},
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "src/**/*.spec.ts",
  "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
],
"compileOnSave": false,
"atom": {
  "rewriteTsconfig": false
}
}
```

my tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

We use:

- Angular 5.0.1
- Ionic 4.4.0
- Cordova Android 6.3.0
- Cordova iOS 4.5.4
- Ionic-Plugin-Keyboard 2.2.1
- Angular-CLI 1.6.2
- Karma 1.7.1
- Jasmine 2.8.0
- Typescript 2.4.2

I try to create a UnitTest with Testbed like shown in this tutorial:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/change-detection/

But it fails with above Stacktrace. If I follow the Exception I find out that this `ele['__zone_symbol__addEventListener']` call throws it.

The method in `.../es2015/platform/platform.js` is called by this line `platform.registerListener(platform.doc(), 'keydown', keyDown, evOpts)` in `.../es2015/platform/keyboard.js` and the `doc()` returns a type of `HTML` seen here `doc(): HTMLDocument;`.

So maybe there is a problem with initialisation of the HTML but I'm not experienced with such deep framework issues.

I only get this error when running Unit Tests with `Testbed`. Our tests for pipes and our app build works without a problem.